# @ionic-native/camera vs. @ionic-native/media-capture

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've started to work with Ionic, just to have some experience with it. And so far I like and hate it.

I hate it, because it's confusing sometimes. Like in this case: what should I use @ionic-native/camera or @ionic-native/media-capture to take pictures? The examples I found use the first one, but I see that the second one provides me with more information about the picture after taking it (such as width/height).

So - which should I use? And if I am supposed the first one, how can I retrieve the image information (e.g. width/height) afterwards?

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I really can't find good information regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: Use whatever plugin you want.

Both of the plugins have an ionic-native wrapper available ([cordova-plugin-media-capture](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/) and [cordova-plugin-camera](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)). If the media-capture plugin fits your needs better you should use this one. Both plugins are maintained by Apache so they should both be of high quality.

So whats the difference then?

The media-capture plugin simply offers more functionality than the camera one. You can capture Audio, Video and Photos and with cordova-plugin-camera you can only capture single photos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Helps me a lot. I wasn't sure if one of them is deprecated or something. Sometimes ionic is really confusing.

Comment: Just check the official github repos of the plugins (they are linked on top of the ionic-native docs), if a plugin is deprecated or no longer maintained you will find a notice there.